# Rails/Rspec: Empty rspec scenario produces `duplicate key value` error in other tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a bunch of Rspec feature tests in my app. After adding one new scenario to this spec

```
feature "DoStuff", type: :feature do
  let!(:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:account) }
  let!(:user) { ... }
  let!(:user2) { ... }
  let!( ... ) { ... }

  before do
    account.switch!
    switch_to_subdomain(account.subdomain)
    Category.first.assign_user(user)
    Category.first.assign_user(user2)
    @product = user.products.first
    @product2 = user2.products.first
    @description = FactoryGirl.create(:description, product: @product)
    @description2 = FactoryGirl.create(:description, product: @product2)
  end

  context "context" do
    before(:each) do
      visit product_path(@product)
    end

    scenario "user can mark product", js: :true do
      expect(@product.questions.first.correct).to eq(true)
      find(".question_1", match: :first, visible: false).click
      wait_for_ajax
      @product.reload

      expect ....
    end
  end
end
```

I got an error

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
   PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "questions_pkey"
   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

The weird thing is that when I comment all the content of the spec out - it still causes an error, just scenario with name. Could anyone suggest what the thing here could be?

Update:
My `database_cleaner` setup:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Apartment::Tenant.reset
  end
end
```

Product factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name "Name"
    current_question 3

    after(:create) do |product|
      question1 = create(:question1)
      question2 = create(:question2)
      question3 = create(:question3)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You'd better show more of the spec and the error.

Comment: Could you copy-paste your relevant factories and database cleaner, for just in case, so I could inspect it?

Comment: @Aleks updated question

Comment: Ok, I will be updating my answer as it is easier to write then in the comments. Could you try with those changes, and let me know if it works?

Comment: @Vla Also paste the code with `let!(:product)(create :product)` and possible others, as it is the most relevant part

Comment: @Aleks 
1) actually I am not creating product here, It is done on the background by other method like `user.init_account`

2) ps: db cleaner fix didn't work

Comment: @Vla could you comment out all the spec code again (like you noted) and run `bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`. And run the that commented spec again. Does the error report then as well? (just to isolate the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Test whether this problem still occurs if you comment this code and reset test database.

Seems like Rspec didn't clear db properly after one scenario and this causes problem, when you try to add new record.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but my db cleaner is set properly, and resetting db actually doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to replace:

```
config.append_after(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.clean
   Apartment::Tenant.reset
end
```

With:

```
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  Apartment::Tenant.reset
end
```

Comment: `Don't run two tests at a same time next time` - what do You mean? I run all tests at the same time, that's why issue is there, as it doesn't occure for single-test.

btw - I run `rake db:test:prepare` and it doesn't help. everything is fine until moment I add empty scenario to the spec above, then I get multiple described errors in 3-4 other specs.

Comment: Usually when someone runs two tests at a same time, in two different terminals, for example, then this error occurs, that is why that note. Could you update the factories and spec_helper, so I could take a look at it?